# Как поставить ограничение на максимальный размер загружаемого файла в django (или в nginx)?

Tags: django, nginx, ddos

На моем сайте пользователи могут создавать статьи с картинками. Я делаю так:

```
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()

def index(request):
    form = ImageForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            anymodel.image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            anymodel.save()

    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form})
```

Я обнаружил, что в request.FILES может лежать файл любого размера, и как сказано в документации django: при размере файла больше 2.5 мб он записывается на диск

Меня волнует, что любой может загрузить и записать файл любого размера на жесткий диск сервера. Как запретить django загружать файлы больше 2.5 мб? Может быть можно поставить ограничение на nginx, если да, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте параметр [client_max_body_size](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) конфигурации Nginx.